# Using loops and ints

Tags: java, loops

So I have a basic project that does this:

User inputs a number 1-10

program prints all numbers below it added together

For example:

user inputs 6

program prints " 1+2+3+4+5+6=21"

Here is what I have

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Loop {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        int num;
        int sum = 0;
        int temp = 1;

        do {
            System.out.print("Enter a number 1-10: ");
            num = in.nextInt();
        } while (!(num > 0 && num <= 10));

        System.out.print("\n");


        while (temp != num) {
            System.out.print(temp + "+");
            sum += ++temp;
        }
        sum += 1;
        System.out.print(num + "=" + sum);
    }

}
```

Okay I changed the code

sum += ++temp;

now all the sums are one off?

I added
sum += 1;
after the while loop but is there another way to fix it?

Comment: You never increment `temp`.

Comment: I am using temp to increase sum. but I dont think im incrementing temp

Comment: @user3250237: exactly, and temp is always 0.

Comment: @user3250237 That's right. And since `temp` is initialized to `0`, you just add `0` to `sum`, forever. Just make sure you add `1` to `temp` on each pass, and you'll be fine.

Comment: So how do I print 1+2+3+4+5+6=21? just add 1 to temp?

Comment: @user3250237 Also note that this sum could be calculated in a smarter way without using loops : `sum = (num * (num + 1)) / 2`

Comment: For more about ZouZou's comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1_%2B_2_%2B_3_%2B_4_%2B_%E2%8B%AF
Tough this defeats the purpose of the exercise :P

Comment: Do I initialize temp as 1? or add 1 to temp
    while(temp != num){
          System.out.print(temp+"+");
          sum += temp (HERE +1);
        }

Comment: You state `while (temp != num) { ... }`. For this loop to have a chance to end, either temp, or num or both must be modified inside the loop. Remember, your program wiull slavishly do, what you said. In this case, it prints an infinite amount of "0+", because temp never changes and is always not equal to num.

Comment: To get rid of the starting 0, just start temp at 1 and reverse the order of your add and your print.

Comment: Okay temp = 1 now. But all the sums are one under. and when i switch the order instead of 1+2+3+4+5=14 it says 2+3+4+5+5=20

Comment: `temp` is a ***terrible*** name for a variable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have the `temp` variable to track the current number you're adding, but you don't ever change it.  Change:

```
sum += ++temp;
```

instead of

```
sum += temp;
```

Comment: Bad advice, this is clearly a very basic programming exercise, do not use `sum += ++temp;` it might be confusing for a newbie. He needs to do two things so it's more clear and readable to make two statements

Comment: OK, It's the same `temp = temp++; sum +=temp`. 
Difference between `t++` and `++t` is that in the first one use t in operation then increase and in second operation increase the t then participate to operation. @user3250237

Comment: Thank you! It is displaying all the numbers now

Comment: @AshotKarakhanyan `temp = temp++`?  AAAAAACCCCKKKKKK!  Please do not assign to a variable and apply an auto-increment to the same variable in the same expression, unless you want to drive everybody crazy.

Comment: Yeah, this looks like crazy :) This is the same temp++ and temp = temp + 1.

Comment: How do I make it not look crazy?

Comment: @user3250237 Just `temp++;`.  That's a statement that adds 1 to `temp`.

Answer (score 0):

I might not be familiar with java, but i guess you can do the loop like this

```
int temp =0;
int inputedNumber = 6;
for(int a = 1; a <= inputedNumber; a++){
 temp += a;
}
cout << temp;
```

Answer (score 0):

just for fun use this function :)

```
  private static String oOo(int OoO) {
    if (OoO == 1) return "1";
    return oOo(OoO - 1) + "+" + String.valueOf(OoO);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I prefer using of For loop, you can do this with some fun ..

// number is the user input and you must validate it before

```
for (int i = number; i >= 1; i--) {
    if (i == 1) {
        System.out.print(i);
        sum = sum + 1;
    } else {
        System.out.print(i + " + ");
        sum = sum + i;
    }
}
System.out.print(" = " + sum);
```